# Keep textarea contents after navigating away from page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session

I have a simple textarea input element:

```
<textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
```

It's on a page that a user will add items to, thus it will be navigated to and away from frequently. If a user types stuff in the textarea element and navigates away, they'll have to retype everything.

How can I make it such that whatever typed in the textarea element will store even if a user navigates away from the page? I don't want there to be a "save" button which then stores it in $_SESSION or SQL, I'm hopeful there's a method that keeps text there without also having to navigate to a new page. To clarify, sessions are A-OK, but I just don't want the user to have to press anything to store it, I'd like it automatically.

Comment: You should look at using [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Use localStorage

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    localStorage.setItem('comment-save', document.getElementById('commment').value);
}
```

Then when the page is loaded

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('comment').value = localStorage.getItem('comment-save');
}
```

### Explanation

`window.onbeforeunload` will run code before the page is closed. You can always change the event, for example

```
document.getElementById('comment').input
```

should save the value every time the user types something. The next line will store the `textarea` value in a `localStorage` item called *comment-save*

---

The code block will run when the page loads. It will locate the `#comment` textarea and set it's value to the saved comment.

### One Last Problem

If the user submits the comment, you probably don't want to store it anymore. In your submit code, add

```
localStorage.removeItem('comment-save');
```

### Why

Why use this over PHP? PHP is over-kill to save client-side data. It also wastes server-side resources.